# ISZ (compressed ISO format) viewer for Mac OS X

Tags: iso-image, osx-leopard

Is there any utility available that mount or view ISZ files (the compressed ISO format used by Ultra ISO) in Mac OS X?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it uses bzip2 for compression. Maybe it's possible to use that command line program to convert it to a regular ISO?

Comment: @SamSol I know, 8 years later.. but have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Linux or OSX, this python script works great for me:

https://github.com/oserres/isz-tool/zipball/master

usuage

```
./oserres-isz-tool-1c8541e/isz-tool.py isz2iso try.isz
Extracting try.isz to try.iso -
Done
```

i was really surprised by the effectiveness of this compression:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 domdorn  staff   3,1G 10 Jan 18:06 try.iso
-rw-r--r--@  1 domdorn  staff   991M 10 Jan 18:04 try.isz
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen your answer. Thanks for effort. 

Comment: if it solves your problem, would u mind accepting it as your answer? thx

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with it, but [AnyToISO](http://www.crystalidea.com/isz-to-iso-open-isz-convert-isz-to-iso-extract-isz-windows-and-mac) claims to be able to convert an ISZ to ISO. From there you can mount or burn it normally.